# ¿Como obtengo los datos de 2 tablas si cumple una condición en una consulta con laravel?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo 2 tablas:

tabla **preguntas:**

```
Schema::create('preguntas', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('evaluaciones_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('evaluaciones_id')->references('id')->on('evaluaciones');
    $table->integer('tipo');
    $table->double('puntaje', 15, 2);
    $table->string('descrip');
    $table->integer('numero');
    $table->boolean('v_f');
    $table->string('seleccion', 1);
    $table->string('desarrollo');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

tabla **preguntas_selecciones:**

```
Schema::create('preguntas_selecciones', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('preguntas_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('preguntas_id')->references('id')->on('preguntas');
    $table->string('item', 1);
    $table->string('text');
    $table->integer('numero');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Realizo la consulta de la siguiente manera, acá llamo todos los registros cuando cumplen la condición **where**, si el registro en la tabla **pregunta** es de ***tipo=2*** pues se registran datos en la tabla **preguntas_selecciones**, es decir, no siempre van a haber datos en la tabla **preguntas_selecciones**, dependerá de la columna ***tipo*** que sea ***2*** en la tabla **preguntas**. A continuación la consulta que tengo actualmente:

```
$valores = Pregunta::select(array(
        'preguntas.tipo',
        'preguntas.puntaje',
        'preguntas.descrip',
        'preguntas.numero',
        'preguntas.v_f',
        'preguntas.seleccion',
        'preguntas.desarrollo',
        //donde acá deberían ir los registros q contiene los tipo 2, de no ser así no colocar nada
    ))
    ->where('preguntas.evaluaciones_id', '=', $valor->id)
    ->orderBy('preguntas.numero', 'asc')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
return $valores;
```

**NOTA:** la consulta de la tabla **preguntas** se realizan correctamente, solo desconozco como puedo agregar los registros que hay en la tabla **preguntas_selecciones** si la columna de la tabla **preguntas** es del **tipo es 2**.

Comment: ¿cómo está definida la relación?

Comment: @Shaz de uno a muchos, **preguntas_id** es la relación, explico: de un registro en la tabla **preguntas** puede tener una o muchas **preguntas_selecciones**

Comment: A ver si entiendo bien: Digamos que hay una consulta que da como resultado 9 preguntas (Ejemplo: 3 de tipo 1, 3 de tipo 2 y 3 de tipo 3). Entonces quieres obtener esas 6 preguntas y además la relación ÚNICAMENTE para las 3 preguntas de tipo 2?

Comment: quisiera obtener las 9 preguntas y de las 9 hay 3 tipo 2 esas 3 relacionarlas con la tabla **preguntas_selecciones**.

Comment: @Shaz y si, la relación ÚNICAMENTE para las 3 preguntas de tipo 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

debera de existir en tus modelos las relaciones.
Suponiendo que **Preguntas** es el modelo de la tabla ***preguntas*** y **PreguntaSeleccione** es el modelo de la tabla ***preguntas_selecciones***, tendriamos lo siguiente:
En tu Modelo **Preguntas**:

```
public function preguntaseleciones(){
    return $this->hasMany(PreguntasSeleccione::class,'preguntas_id');
}
```

en tu modelo **PreguntaSeleccione**:

```
public function pregunta(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Preguntas::class,'preguntas_id');
}
```

Ahora la consulta en tu controlador seria:

```
$valores = Pregunta::with('preguntaselecciones')
    ->where('evaluaciones_id', $valor->id)
    ->where('tipo',2)
    ->orderBy('numero')
    ->get();
```

Y pues bueno como accedes a sus datos??
accedemos a los **preguntas_selecciones** de la primera **preguntas**:

```
$valores[0]->preguntaselecciones
```

eso te retorna un array de todos los preguntas_selecciones ligados al primer dato